# How to indent applescript when running in bash script?

Tags: bash, osascript

```
osascript -e "set x to 3"
osascript -e "if x is 5 then"
osascript -e "    tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke return"
osascript -e "end if"
```

The output i get

```
14:14: syntax error: Expected end of line but found end of script. (-2741)
0:6: syntax error: A “if” can’t go after this “end”. (-2740)
```

Can't see whats wrong with the script. Might be some issue with indentation. Anyone used osascript inside bash files ?

Answer (score 0):

Put all your applescript lines together. This way:

```
osascript -e "set x to 3
if x is 5 then
tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke return
end if"
```

Additionally, you can create a file like the following with all your applescript code:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
set x to 3
if x is 5 then
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke return
end if
```

Comment: Looks interesting, i'll try this! Do you know how to run applescript from a file inside bash?

Answer (score 0):

I find this way easiest in respect of quoting and double-quoting and escaping, and using `bash` variables in the `osascript`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set bash variable to 3, then use it in osascript
count=3

osascript <<EOF
beep $count

tell application "Safari"
   set theURL to URL of current tab of window 1
end tell
EOF

# Continue in bash
echo done
```