# Using mdls for tags and rysc to backup data? (OSX)

Tags: macos, backup, rsync, mdls

I'm using rsync to make some regularly backups.
Now I want to exclude all files and folders with a red an orange tag. As I learned using tags in OSX isn't available as a criteria to rsync. But with an extension to mdls it would be possible.
But I don't have any glue how?
Any hints or examples?
Thanks in advance
Dirk

Summary: I already run rsync successfully. But mdls I didn't understand as well, as the result of mdls would be a filter to rsync.

Answer (score 0):

I am not in a position to test this, but you should be able to get something working if you use this as a starting point.

The general idea is to use `rsync`'s `--exclude-from "excluded.txt"` option to specify the things you don't want included in your backup, like this:

```
rsync -avz --exclude-from "excluded.txt" source/ destination/
```

where `"excluded.txt"` contains one line per file or directory you wish to exclude. Try making a simple two-line `excluded.txt` by hand to see if you can get the hang of it first.

---

One the **macOS** side, you need to use `mdfind` to find your red-tagged or orange-tagged files. The basic starting point is:

```
mdfind -onlyin SOMEDIRECTORY 'tag:red OR tag:orange'
```

Maybe you actually mean `'tag:red AND tag:orange'`? This will produce a list of files (and directories) tagged that way, so you will then want to redirect that to a file when it looks right using:

```
mdfind -onlyin SOMEDIRECTORY 'tag:red OR tag:orange' > excluded.txt
```

And then you can join the two commands:

```
mdfind -onlyin SOMEDIRECTORY 'tag:red OR tag:orange' > excluded.txt
rsync -avz --exclude-from "excluded.txt" source/ destination/
```

There are ways of doing that without creating a temporary file, but I'm not sure if you want anything that complicated:

```
rsync -avz --exclude-from <(mdfind -onlyin SOMEDIRECTORY 'tag:red OR tag:orange')  source/ destination/
```

---

Note also that I believe `rsync` uses only **relative** paths for the `--exclude-from` parameter, so you may need to convert absolute to relative paths.

---

Note there's an excellent intro to `mdfind` by Michael Klement that I commend to you for reading and upvoting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30281424/2836621).

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot. This is a lot of stuff. I will try my very best! :-)

Comment: I tried this too (have to specify colors in local language):
mdfind -onlyin . "kMDItemUserTags == 'Orange' || kMDItemUserTags == 'Rot'" > excluded.txt

But as you stated, there is a need to convert the output for --exclude-from parameter, but I don't know how. Any hint?

Comment: @PeterSilie You need the equivalent POSIX paths of the Appley paths, https://www.satimage.fr/software/en/smile/external_codes/file_paths.html If you are using `bash` it's something like `osascript <<EOF ...` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29937926/2836621

Comment: @PeterSilie You may want to ask on apple.stackexchange.com how to convert a file full of absolute Applescript paths into relative POSIX paths.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know "apple.stackexchange.com". I will have a look. Thanks.  BTW: I'm using zsh (the newest standard apple shell)